# Appending values from a text file to an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, user-defined-functions

I have this program that calculates an approximation to the derivative of sin(pi/3). The print gives this output into a txt file:

```
delta_x: 1.000000e-01, df_approx: 4.5590188541e-01, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 4.409811e-02,           rel_error: 8.819623e-02, n=1
delta_x: 1.000000e-02, df_approx: 4.9566157577e-01, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 4.338424e-03,           rel_error: 8.676848e-03, n=2
delta_x: 1.000000e-03, df_approx: 4.9956690400e-01, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 4.330960e-04,           rel_error: 8.661920e-04, n=3
delta_x: 1.000000e-04, df_approx: 4.9995669790e-01, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 4.330210e-05,           rel_error: 8.660421e-05, n=4
delta_x: 1.000000e-05, df_approx: 4.9999566987e-01, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 4.330133e-06,           rel_error: 8.660266e-06, n=5
delta_x: 1.000000e-06, df_approx: 4.9999956697e-01, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 4.330281e-07,           rel_error: 8.660562e-07, n=6
delta_x: 1.000000e-07, df_approx: 4.9999995699e-01, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 4.300676e-08,           rel_error: 8.601353e-08, n=7
delta_x: 1.000000e-08, df_approx: 4.9999999696e-01, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 3.038736e-09,           rel_error: 6.077471e-09, n=8
delta_x: 1.000000e-09, df_approx: 5.0000004137e-01, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 4.137019e-08,           rel_error: 8.274037e-08, n=9
delta_x: 1.000000e-10, df_approx: 5.0000004137e-01, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 4.137019e-08,           rel_error: 8.274037e-08, n=10
delta_x: 1.000000e-11, df_approx: 5.0000004137e-01, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 4.137019e-08,           rel_error: 8.274037e-08, n=11
delta_x: 1.000000e-12, df_approx: 5.0004445029e-01, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 4.445029e-05,           rel_error: 8.890058e-05, n=12
delta_x: 1.000000e-13, df_approx: 4.9960036108e-01, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 3.996389e-04,           rel_error: 7.992778e-04, n=13
delta_x: 1.000000e-14, df_approx: 4.9960036108e-01, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 3.996389e-04,           rel_error: 7.992778e-04, n=14
delta_x: 1.000000e-15, df_approx: 5.5511151231e-01, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 5.511151e-02,           rel_error: 1.102230e-01, n=15
delta_x: 1.000000e-16, df_approx: 0.0000000000e+00, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 5.000000e-01,           rel_error: 1.000000e+00, n=16
delta_x: 1.000000e-17, df_approx: 0.0000000000e+00, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 5.000000e-01,           rel_error: 1.000000e+00, n=17
delta_x: 1.000000e-18, df_approx: 0.0000000000e+00, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 5.000000e-01,           rel_error: 1.000000e+00, n=18
delta_x: 1.000000e-19, df_approx: 0.0000000000e+00, df_exact: 5.0000000000e-01, abs_error: 5.000000e-01,           rel_error: 1.000000e+00, n=19
```

Now I want to write a function that reads the file and returns three arrays consisting of numbers corresponding to **delta_x, abs_error and n**. How would I do that? Because I have to plot these arrays into a graph as well later, but I can't wrap my head around on how to actually extract the wanted values with a function that returns arrays for each of the values that I calculated? I have tried with this code, but I get ridiculous print:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

k=19 #number of calculations
abs_error=np.zeros(k)
n=np.zeros(k)
delta_x=np.zeros(k)

def extract_data(filename):
    infile = open('approx_derivative_sine.txt', 'r')

    for line in infile:
        words=line.split()
        #words[0]: delta_x, words[1]: value for delta_x
        np.append(delta_x, words[1])
        np.append(abs_error, words[7])
        np.append(n, words[10])
        
    return delta_x,abs_error,n

print(extract_data(0))
```

the print is:

```
(array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0.]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0.]), array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0.]))
```

Which is completely wrong, because each array is supposed to have float values from delta_x, abs_error and n that is in the txt file. When I do it as a list it works, but I have to use arrays. Anyone got an idea how to fix it? Can anyone write a code that works???

Comment: `np.append` is not a list append cline.  Don't use it in the same way.  Better yet don't use it at all.

Comment: how do i fix it? what would you different

Comment: How would you rewrite it, i dont understand what you mean

Comment: Pull up an interactive Python session and experiement.  When collecting data from file lines we often use lists, starting with `[]` and appending values at each line.  That's straightforward Python coding.  Save the array creation to the end.

Comment: I dont udnerstand @hpaulj, can you explain further?

Comment: Where did you get the idea of creating np.zeros(k) and iterating with np.append(...) from? It obviously wasn't from any numpy documentation or tutorial.  Alternatively, explain why you think your code should work.  What's the rational for each step?  It doesn't work to write programs with guesses.